# Magento Admin Custom Module Menu tab not showing

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created a custom admin module and added a menu tab, After that I set `ACL` role & permission but it's not showing the menu item. See below screen

[image]

**But When I log in with specified user. It's not showing.**

[image]

My config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bluehorse_Warehouse>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </Bluehorse_Warehouse>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <warehouse>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Bluehorse_Warehouse</module>
                    <frontName>warehouse</frontName>
                </args>
            </warehouse>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <warehouse>
                    <file>warehouse.xml</file>
                </warehouse>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <warehouse>
                <class>Bluehorse_Warehouse_Helper</class>
            </warehouse>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <warehouse>
                <class>Bluehorse_Warehouse_Block</class>
            </warehouse>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <warehouse>
                <class>Bluehorse_Warehouse_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>warehouse_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </warehouse>
            <warehouse_mysql4>
                <class>Bluehorse_Warehouse_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <warehouse>
                        <table>bh_warehouse</table>
                    </warehouse>
                    <zipcode>
                        <table>bh_zipcode</table>
                    </zipcode>
                    <product>
                        <table>bh_product</table>
                    </product>
                </entities>
            </warehouse_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <warehouse_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Bluehorse_Warehouse</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </warehouse_setup>
            <warehouse_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </warehouse_write>
            <warehouse_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </warehouse_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Bluehorse_Warehouse before="Mage_Adminhtml">Bluehorse_Warehouse_Adminhtml</Bluehorse_Warehouse>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <warehouse>
                    <file>warehouse.xml</file>
                </warehouse>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

And my adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <warehouses translate="title" module="warehouse">
            <title>Warehouse</title>
            <sort_order>80</sort_order>
            <children>
                <!-- child items go here -->
                <index translate="title" module="warehouse">
                    <title>Warehouse Manage</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/warehouse/</action>
                </index>
            </children>
        </warehouses>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <warehouse translate="title" module="warehouse">
                                        <title>Warehouse</title>
                                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                    </warehouse>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>   
                    <warehouse translate="title" module="index">
                        <title>Warehouse list</title>
                        <sort_order>-100</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <index translate="title">
                                <title>Index Action</title>
                                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            </index>
                        </children>
                    </warehouse>    
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

And  I had added in my Controller

```
protected function _isAllowed() {
    $adminSession = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
    return $adminSession->isAllowed('warehouse/index');
}
```

its not showing the tab in menu.

I also tying many blogs but not solved my problem

Please help me.

Comment: i will check and let u know

Answer (score 1):

Try to add to the your controller:

```
protected function _isAllowed() 
{
    return true; // just for test
}
```

Log out/Log in. Then try to check again.

If it helps, modify your `_isAllowed` method:

```
protected function _isAllowed() 
{
    $aclResource = 'yours/module/acl/path';
    return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed($aclResource);
}
```

Comment: Giving the same error.

Comment: Try to debug Mage_Admin_Model_Session::isAllowed

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: At first check (in Mage_Admin_Model_Session::isAllowed) that the path of a resource similar with path in acl rules of your module

Comment: When I checking with logged by administrator role its return `true`, but checking with one another user its not showing. Gives the same error.

Comment: Try to check deeper and find in which place the code returns "false". For the super-administrator its always returns true (a privilege rule).

Comment: In addition try to change $adminSession->isAllowed('warehouse/index'); to $adminSession->isAllowed('admin/warehouse/index');